# ActionController::RoutingError fontawesome

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

```
Completed 200 OK in 7905ms (Views: 7560.5ms | ActiveRecord: 3.1ms | Solr: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-29 22:18:49 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff"):


Rendered /Users/bet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.1ms)


Started GET "/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-29 22:18:50 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf"):


Rendered /Users/bet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.0ms)


Started GET "/font/fontawesome-webfont.svgz" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-29 22:18:50 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/font/fontawesome-webfont.svgz"):


Rendered /Users/bet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.1ms)


Started GET "/font/fontawesome-webfont.svg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-29 22:18:50 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/font/fontawesome-webfont.svg"):


Rendered /Users/bet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.0ms)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue. I'm using the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem.

Comment: I left it alone since I posted this and now trying to fix it again.